# Is the Central Limit Theorem applicable on weighted variables?

Tags: central-limit-theorem, weights

I have a set of iid random variables $(X_n)$ and a set of real positive weights $w_n \in \mathbb{R^{*+}}$ that can be seen as another set of random variables not independant of $(X_n)$.

I would like to estimate a confidence interval of the limit of the weighted arithmetic mean $\overline{X}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{w_i}\cdot X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{w_i}}$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$.

- Is there any version of the CLT that is applicable without condition on the weights?
- What if $w_n \in [1, \infty]$?
- If $w_n \in [0,1]$ ?
- If $w_n \in [0,1]$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{w_i}=1$?

Comment: Fischer seems to have tackled the problem in 1992: https://www.jstor.org/stable/44238359?seq=1 and I also found this more recent paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715206000824

Comment: There's no distinction between your last three bullets because $\bar X$ is a function only of $w_i/\sum w_i \in [0,1].$